# Which shloka explains this statement related to Shiva

Tags: shiva, identification-request, shloka

If a person falls in dangerous situations such as in front of dangerous animals, then if such person says "**Shiva**", then the total situation comes under control and the animals don't harm that person.

Which Hindu scripture contains this?

Comment: I had read it's shlok and possibly on this Hinduism Stack Exchange itself somewhere.